# Question about using articles

Tags: grammar

1. Popcorn popped in the pan
2. Kernel is small

Do I need an article in front of each sentence or are they okay as they are?

Answer (score 1):

In English, you generally need an article when you use any noun in the singular. Exceptions are: You do not use an article with most proper nouns, i.e. names of specific things. You do not use an article if you use a possessive pronoun. You do not need an article with an uncountable noun.

Even when you don't NEED an article, you sometimes use "the" to say that you are talking about some specific instance of the thing.

Examples:

"The dog is brown." Needs an article because it is singular and doesn't meet any of the exceptions.

"My dog is brown." Doesn't need an article because it has a possessive instead.

"Sally's dog is brown." Same.

"Dogs have four legs." No article because it is plural.

"Rover is brown." (I'm assuming "Rover" is the name of a dog.) No article because it's a proper noun.

"Water is wet." No article because "water" (as used here) is uncountable.

So in your examples:

#1 doesn't need an article because "popcorn" is an uncountable noun. We wouldn't say that you have "three popcorns". Well, you need the article in front of "pan" because pan is a singular noun and doesn't meet any of the exceptions.

#2 needs an article because "kernel" is a singular noun and doesn't meet the exceptions. You should say, "A kernel is small" or "The kernel is small". You could also make it plural: "Kernels are small."

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For #1, I can also say "The popcorn popped in the pan", right?

Comment: Yes, you can if you are referring to a particular batch of popcorn.